Enabling Real-Time Kernel in WSL2
Can I enable Real-time kernel in WSL2?
If yes, I keep getting this error:
Cannot install Real-time kernel on a container.
Could not enable Real-time kernel.

Also using pro status --all, the output is
realtime-kernel yes **n/a** Ubuntu kernel with PREEMPT_RT patches integrated
├ generic yes **n/a** Generic version of the RT kernel (default)
├ intel-iotg yes **n/a** RT kernel optimized for Intel IOTG platform
└ raspi yes **n/a** 24.04 Real-time kernel optimised for Raspberry Pi

If the answer is no, why? and is there any plan to support?
I am running Ubuntu-22.04 on top of WSL2 on Windows 11 using an Intel Core-I5 machine.
Thank you in advance.

The kernel in WSL is not part of Ubuntu, so there is nothing to install or manager from the Ubuntu side.
